# Assign the value of awk-for loop variable to a bash variable

Tags: bash, awk

content within the tempfile

```
123 sam moore IT_Team
235 Rob Xavir Management
```

What i'm trying to do is get input from user and search it in the tempfile and output of search should give the column number

Code I have for that

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x;
read -p "Enter :" sword6;
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1 }
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if( $i ~ "'$sword6'$" )
            print i;
    }
} ' /root/scripts/pscripts/tempprint.txt;
```

This exactly the column number

Output

```
Enter : sam
2
```

What i need is the value of i variable should be assigned to bash variable so i can call as per the need in script.

Any help in this highly appreciated.

I searched to find any existing answer but not able to find any. If any let me know please.

Comment: What do you need the column number for? If it's for further processing, you might as well do that in the same `awk` script.

Answer (score 1):

- first of all, you should pass your shell variable to awk in this way (e.g. `sword6`)

  ```
  awk -v word="$sword6" '{.. if($i ~ word)...}`...
  ```
- to assign shell variable by the output of other command:

  ```
  shellVar=$(awk '......')
  ```

Then you can continue using `$shellVar` in your script.

### regarding your awk codes:

- if user input some special chars, your script may fail, e.g `.*`
- if one column had matched userinput multiple times, you may have duplicated output.
- if your file had multi-columns matching user input, you may want to handle it.

Comment: got it, I'm using if condition this query will work only when match count is  equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

You just need to capture the output of `awk`. As an aside, I would pass `sword6` as an `awk` variable, not inject it via string interpolation.

```
i=$(awk -v w="$sword6" '
        BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
        { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if ($i ~ w"$") { print i; }
          }
        }' /root/scripts/pscipts/tempprint.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following script may help you on same too.

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter the user name:"
read var
awk -v val="$var" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(tolower($i)==tolower(val)){print i,$i}}}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If tempprint.txt is big

```
awk -v w="$word6" '
BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1 }
"$0 ~ \\<w\\>" {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i==w)print i
}' tempprint.txt
```